# How to enable and configure topics for objects in lightning?

Tags: lightning-community, topics

How to enable and configure topics for objects in lightning? FYI. I don't see topics for objects in quick find box.  I have build community using Napili Template in lightning but I can't add articles under navigation menu and assign them using data categories.
I get this error when I try to add articles :

Assigning the topics you've selected isn't allowed. A Salesforce admin must enable topics for objects for the article type(s).

Answer (score 2):

Switch to classic and search for topics for objects in the quick find box, this option/setting is not yet available in lightning experience.

LEX:

[image]

Classic:

[image]

> Enable and Configure Topics for Objects
>
> - From Setup, enter Topics for Objects in the Quick Find box, then select Topics for Objects.
> - Select an object.
> - At the right, select Enable Topics.
> - Select the text fields that you want to use for topic suggestions. (From a combination of the selected fields, up to 3 suggestions are
>     made from the first 2,000 characters.)
> - Click Save to save changes for all objects.

If you mean Topics for lightning communties, you should check your community management:

[image]

Overall, if you are are refering to data categories, this is a completely different topic. your post is not clear and confusing.

Comment: I tried but still can't see Topics for Objects in classic as well. I got two options under Topics 1. Topic Triggeres & Topic assignment Triggers.

Comment: Hi, your original psot is very confusing and you seem to be mixing up topic for object, alongside navigational topics and data categories....

Answer (score 2):

Bumping a year later: In Summer '18, Topics rolled out in Lightning.
https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_general_topics_on_records.htm

To make Topics visible in Lightning, after enabling them for the object, edit the object's Record Detail page in Lightning App Builder and add the Topics component.